# Publishing API for Access

Tags: iis

I developed an API on Visual Studio 2022 that retrieves some data and will also add data to a Database.  On my local development environment, I can access the API from the following link: https://localhost:7224/Forms and get results back from the query.

[image]

Then, I published the API, as I would any .NET Web Site to a URL that I created for the API. Installed a TLS Certificate for the website as well.

[image]

The API was published to a Web site URL and a SSL/TLS Certificate was created for it to run under https protocol:

[image]

There were no errors during the published event.

I tried at this point to reach the API without success.  I tried the URL on its own as well as the URL:7224 without success. I modified the port and changed it from 443 to 7224.  Restarted the IIS.  NO data.  The URL reroutes to a blank index.html page.

If I can get the data locally, how do I set up IIS on the Web Server to deliver on the API Request?

Comment: You need to edit the question and show us how you deployed it. Common mistakes can be there and errors are expected.

Comment: You literally showed us nothing new after edits. If you are not sure what’s the IIS configuration needed to be shown, ask a modern AI for guidance.

Comment: If there is a specific IIS Configuration that Is required for an API to work from a Web Server, please share it with me.  I published the API just like I was publishing a Web Site build on .NEt Core.  I am not sure what else to do.  Hence my question here.  If this is not the right place to ask for help, then I will gladly ask elsewhere.  I did Ask Chagt GPT and was guided to check the firewall and permissions, which I did, and set the port to 7224.  As I indicated, the current API works on my development environment as is and I posted the link that works. Please help if you can.  Tks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Then start from telling viewers what site/application you configured on IIS.

Comment: You do not need to change the port number to 7224 in IIS, this port number is randomly generated when you run the application from Visual Studio and has nothing to do with the port number configured in IIS. Do you just get a blank page without any error message? Please check the IIS logs and browser console, provide us with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the posts here and asking AI about the behavior, I decided that I needed to know more about the reason why one query was okay, while the other was not reporting.  The difference between the two queries that I ran was one was a locally generated value into an array that was used to display an output on the page, while the other was requesting data from a Database on the Web server.

I added some additional Error reporting code that captured what happened during the database query and discovered that the User that I assigned to run queries on the database did not have enough permission to run a query.  Once I updated the permission of the assigned User, the JSON data was available for me from the query.  This was an oversight.  Normally I assign the User and provide the necessary permissions.  This time, the permission part was not done, hence the blank page. Next time, my API will definitely include a Database Permission check.  Thanks to everyone who helped.  Although, I have no idea why this question received a spanking of -1.  I felt bad for asking it, and I should DEFFINITELY know better.